# Get input from Android EditText without changing the content view

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-edittext, monogame

I am using Monogame and Xamarin to create a game for android. A major problem I face is accurately getting keyboard input from the soft keyboard. I am attempting to put text into an EditText and then use a handler to forward the text to the textbox in the game. The problem I am having is that to get keyboard input from the EditText, I must change the ContentView which then makes the game no longer visible.

I have discovered that several older phones do not respond correctly to OnKeyUp or DispatchKeyEvent methods in the Activity (i.e., backspace does not work or has lag and often times some keys do not respond well). I have also tried a KeyListener directly from the view, but that also caused delay in some keys.

In the main activity, I set the ContentView to the Game:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
       _game = new Game1();            
       SetContentView((View)_game.Services.GetService(typeof(View)));

       var inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)this.Application.GetSystemService("input_method");
       var textWatcher = new TextWatcher(_game, this, inputMethodManager);
    }
```

Then when I show the soft keyboard, I have this code in my TextWatcher class, which implements the ITextWatcher interface:

```
    public void ShowKeyboard(object sender, string e)
    {
        if (this._inputMethodManager.IsAcceptingText)
            return;

        _layout = new LinearLayout(_activity);

        //Without this line, the TextWatcher does not capture input text. But with this code, it takes the view away from the game
        _activity.SetContentView(_layout);

        var orientation = _activity.RequestedOrientation;
        if (orientation == ScreenOrientation.Portrait || orientation == ScreenOrientation.ReversePortrait)
            _layout.Orientation = Android.Widget.Orientation.Vertical;// (LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        else
            _layout.Orientation = Android.Widget.Orientation.Horizontal;// (LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

       //Add the EditText to the layout
        _layout.AddView(_textEditor);

        _textEditor.RequestFocus();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e))
        {
            _textEditor.Text = e;
            _textEditor.SelectAll();
        }

        _inputMethodManager.ToggleSoftInput(ShowFlags.Forced, HideSoftInputFlags.ImplicitOnly);
    }
```

How can I get text input from the EditText without changing the view?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MonoGames `KeyboardInput.Show` method.

```
 var name = await KeyboardInput.Show("Name", "What's your name?", "Player");
```

If you need to do this on your own, I would look at the Android source for the above method. It is called `PlatformShow` in this [file](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Input/KeyboardInput.Android.cs)):

The main points from the source are:

1. the asynchronous nature of the calls
2. the thread it is run on: `Game.Activity.RunOnUiThread(()`

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks. I have not seen this class before.